# Is it bad practice to just kick off new threads for blocking operations (Perl)

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-safety, blocking

If doing CPU intensive tasks I believe it is optimal to have one thread per core.  If you have a 4 core CPU you can run 4 instances of a CPU intensive subroutine without any penalty.  For example I once experimentally ran four instances of a CPU intensive algorithm on a four core CPU.  Up to four times the time per process did not decrease.  At the fifth instances all instances took longer.

What is the case for blocking operations?  Let's say I have a list of 1,000 URLs.  I have been doing the following:

(Please don't mind any syntax errors, I just mocked this up)

```
my @threads;
foreach my $url (@urlList) {    
     push @threads, async {
         my $response = $ua->get($url);
         return $response->content;   
     }
}

foreach my $thread (@threads) {
    my $response = $thread->join;
    do_stuff($response); 
}
```

I am essentially kicking off as many threads as there are URLs in the URL list.  If there are a million URLs then a million threads will be kicked off.  Is this optimal, if not what is an optimal number of threads?  Is using threads a good practice for ANY blocking I/O operation that can wait (reading a file, database queries, etc)?

**Related Bonus Question**

Out of curiosity does Perl threads work the same as Python and it's GIL?  With python to get the benefit of multithreading and utilize all cores for CPU intensive tasks you have to use multiprocessing.

Comment: perl doesn't have anything like `GIL` so you can relax :) on the other hand perl threads are memory hungry but if you have enough resources go for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Out of curiosity does Perl threads work the same as Python and it's GIL? With python to get the benefit of multithreading and utilize all cores for CPU intensive tasks you have to use multiprocessing.

No, but the conclusion is the same. Perl *doesn't* have a big lock protecting the interpreter across threads; instead it has a *duplicate interpreter* for each different thread. Since a variable belongs to an interpreter (and only one interpreter), no data is shared by default between threads. When variables are explicitly shared they're placed in a shared interpreter which serializes all accesses to shared variables on behalf of the other threads. In addition to the memory issues mentioned by others here, there are also some serious performance issues with threads in Perl, as well as limitations on the kind of data that can be shared and what you can do with it (see [perlthrtut](http://p3rl.org/perlthrtut) for more info).

The upshot is, if you need to parallelize a lot of IO and you can make it non-blocking, you'll get a lot more performance out of an event loop model than threads. If you need to parallelize stuff that *can't* be made non-blocking, you'll probably have a lot more luck with multi-process than with perl threads (and once you're familiar with that kind of code, it's also easier to debug).

It's also possible to combine the two models (for example, a mostly-single-process evented app that passes off certain expensive work to child processes using [POE::Wheel::Run](http://p3rl.org/POE%3a%3aWheel%3a%3aRun) or [AnyEvent::Run](http://p3rl.org/AnyEvent%3a%3aRun), or a multi-process app that has an evented parent managing non-evented children, or a Node Cluster type setup where you have a number of preforked evented webservers, with a parent that just `accept`s and passes FDs to its children).

There's no silver bullets, though, at least not yet.

Comment: Or also IO::Async::Routine or ::Function, which are also quite similar ideas.

Comment: @LeoNerd thanks, I didn't mean to leave you out, but I didn't know what the right modules were in IO::Async's case :)

Answer (score 4):

From here:
http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

Memory consumption

On most systems, frequent and continual creation and destruction of threads can lead to ever-increasing growth in the memory footprint of the Perl interpreter. While it is simple to just launch threads and then ->join() or ->detach() them, for long-lived applications, **it is better to maintain a pool of threads, and to reuse them for the work needed**, using queues to notify threads of pending work. The CPAN distribution of this module contains a simple example (examples/pool_reuse.pl) illustrating the creation, use and monitoring of a pool of reusable threads.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your code. I see three problems with it:

1. Easy one first: You use `->content` instead of `->decoded_content(charset => 'none')`.

   `->content` returns the raw HTML response body which is useless without information in the headers to decode it (e.g. it might be gzipped). It works sometimes.

   `->decoded_content(charset => 'none')` gives you the actual response. It works always.
2. You process responses in the order requests were made. That means you could be blocked while responses are waiting to be serviced.

   The simplest solution is to place the responses in a [Thread::Queue::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread%3a%3aQueue%3a%3aAny) object.

   ```
   use Thread::Queue::Any qw( );

   my $q = Thread::Queue::Any->new();

   my $requests = 0;
   for my $url (@urls) {
      ++$requests;
      async {
         ...
         $q->enqueue($response);
      };
   }

   while ($requests && my $response = $q->dequeue()) {
      --$requests;
      $_->join for threads->list(threads::joinable);
      ...
   }

   $_->join for threads->list();
   ```
3. You create a lot of threads that are only used once.

   There is a significant amount of overhead to that approach. A common multithreading practice is to create a pool of persistent worker threads. These workers perform whatever job needs to be done, then move on to the next job rather than exiting. Jobs to the pool rather than a specific thread so that the job can be started as soon as possible. In addition to removing thread creation overhead, this allows the number of threads running at a time to be controlled. This is great for CPU-bound tasks.

   However, your needs are different since you're using threads to do asynchronous IO. The CPU overhead of thread creation doesn't impact you as much (though it may impose a startup lag). Memory is fairly cheap, but you're still using far more than you need. Threads are really not ideal for this task.

   There are much better systems for doing asynchronous IO, but they are not necessarily easily available from Perl. In your specific case, though, **you're much better to avoid threads and go with [Net::Curl::Multi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aCurl%3a%3aMulti).** Follow the example in the Synopsis, and you'll get a very fast engine capable of making parallel web requests with very little overhead.

   We at my former employer have switched to Net::Curl::Multi without problem for a high-load mission-critical web site, and we love it.

   It's easy to create a wrapper that creates HTTP::Response objects if you want to limit changes to surrounding code. (This was the case for us.) Note that it helps to have a [reference](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/allfuncs.html) to the underlying library (libcurl) handy since the Perl code is a thin layer over the underlying library, since the documentation is very good, and since it documents all the options you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You might simply want to consider a non-blocking user agent. I like [Mojo::UserAgent](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent) which is part of the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) suite. You might want to look at an example that I mocked up for a non-blocking crawler for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15166898/468327).

Comment: Thank you.  The user agent is one example but I am also asking this for the general case of "long running I/O".  It could be a URL fetch, db query, file read, or something else I haven't thought of yet.  I want to know if threading is the way to handle this and how to optimize the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  Doesn't Mojo do something similar to threading "under the hood" anyway?

Comment: Mojolicious has its own event loop, which will use EV (and thus AnyEvent) if available. Both its own loop and AE have file watchers etc. I have never used these in multicore/thread applications but I'm sure someone has done that legwork (probably?). I might start by looking at AnyEvent and Coro.